# how to debug a dll when you have the source code for it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

**Situation:**

We have a C# application which uses a dll coded by other people. The dll refers to C++ code. The C# application makes the call to the dll through a wrapper (C# functions then call the C++ ones).

**Problem:**

There is a specific call to the C++ code which crashes. I'd need to step into the C++ code. I know it's possible but I have no clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project settings in the debug tab there is a checkbox for "Enable Native code debugging"

[image]

You must have that box checked to be able to step in to the C++ code. Once you have that checked you should be able to step in to the C# code.

If you find you still can not step in disable "Just My Code" in the "Debug" -> "Options and Settings" dropdown menu

[image]

If you still can not step in, be sure you have the `.pdb` file for the dll which contains the debugging metadata, while the program is paused go to the "Debug" -> "Windows" -> "Modules" dropdown and check to see if you see "Symbols loaded" under the symbol status column.

[image]

If you see the DLL but it is not loaded you can right click and go to "Load Symbols" on the line for the DLL and find the pdb.

If you don't see the DLL at all you must run your program forward more till it has used your C++ dll at least once so it has been loaded in to memory.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!! I just wonder where do I put the C++ code so it knows when it uses my dll, it has to jump in a specific C++ code?

Comment: You can't just have the source, you need the pdb too. See my updated version on how to load the pdb.